# Error while running app

Tags: android-layout, android

I have an app with flipper and animation of images on each page of Flipper...
App works on HTC Desire, Desire S, Samsung Galaxy tab 1 (7')... But when I try to run it on Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 - this error occures...

```
flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    int layouts[] = new int[]{ R.layout.first, R.layout.second, R.layout.third, R.layout.fourth, 
            R.layout.fifth, R.layout.sixth, R.layout.seventh, R.layout.eighth, R.layout.nineth, R.layout.tenth, 
            R.layout.eleventh, R.layout.twelveth, R.layout.thirteen, R.layout.fourteenth };
    for (int layout : layouts)
        flipper.addView(inflater.inflate(layout, null)); 

02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.home/com.home.Main}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1751)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1767)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1005)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4028)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:596)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:644)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:457)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:347)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at com.home.Main.onCreate(Main.java:98)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1715)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     ... 11 more
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:416)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:576)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     ... 20 more
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:577)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:445)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:738)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1869)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2462)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2401)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:359)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:173)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     ... 23 more
```

As I understand after googling this error is because of Manifest, any ideas?

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.home"
  android:installLocation="preferExternal"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<supports-screens 
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"/>
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".Main"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="landscape"
              >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>/////// it's on://////flipper.addView(inflater.inflate(layout, null));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is because of `OutOfMemoryError` exception. You're trying to load some heavy enough bitmap from your resources:

```
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:577)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:445)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:738)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1869)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2462)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2401)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:359)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:173)
02-16 09:33:44.129: E/AndroidRuntime(1733):     ... 23 more
```

Comment: ok, I'll take a look... but why everything works on samsung galaxy tab 1? this device is more powerful???

Comment: you were right... but WHY???? why dalvik of samsung is so poor??? Now images are bad!!! What can I do to increase resolution of @drawable... maybe - using doInBackground or anything else?